# Edit app.config file and read settings

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

I have a app.config file.
I have settings there.
I want to modify settings after my build and then read it from file.
I mean I want to change settings by edeting a file.
I know how to change settings programmaticaly but I need it by editing file.

No I'm trying to do so:

```
    private void ReadSettings()
    {
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string settingsPath = Path.Combine(appPath, "app.config");
        ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = settingsPath;
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        string value=config.AppSettings.Settings["Type"].Value;
    }
```

My settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="RxTest.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Type" serializeAs="String">
                <value>document</value>
            </setting>
        </RxTest.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Problem is that there is nothing in Settings property.

What shuld I do to read settings from edeted file?

Answer (score 0):

The UserSettings written in your app.config file should be automatically added into it by adding an entry into your properties.

You can achieve getting the values from your properties like this:

`string value = Properties.Settings.Default.Type;`

---

**EDIT I:**

To be sure you always have the freshest value, you can either [refresh a section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx):

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName);
```

Or you can reaload the file:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
```

Comment: I know how get it and set. But I need to get it after file modified

Comment: If you have made changes in your config, you will get the new value. You just need to get the value after a possible update. E.g. refresh the properties everytime you need the actual value.